# Extracting sentences containing keywords objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyword

I have a block of text (a newspaper article if it's of any relevance) was wondering if there is a way to extract all sentences containing a particular keyword in objective-c? I've been looking a bit at ParseKit but aren't having much luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enumerate sentences using native `NSString` methods like this...

```
NSString *string = @"your text";

NSMutableArray *sentences = [NSMutableArray array];

[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) 
                           options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences 
                        usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    //check that this sentence has the string you are looking for
    NSRange range = [substring rangeOfString:@"The text you are looking for"];

    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        [sentences addObject:substring];
    }
}];

for (NSString *sentence in sentences) {
    NSLog(@"%@", sentence);
}
```

At the end you will have an array of sentences all containing the text you were looking for.

Comment: I think most of the problem is determining the sentences within the article, not just performing text searching.

Comment: This will enumerate by sentences for you. You don't need to determine them yourself. The block function then does the search on each sentence with the text. Hence "NSEnumerationBySentences".

Comment: Can you explain *how* it does that?  I dont't see code to look for full stops (a common way to delimit sentences).

Comment: NSString does it for you. Objective-C has in built functions to enumerate a string by words, sentences and paragraphs. I don't know HOW it does it, it's a native function.

Comment: Ah I see that now, sorry.  I didn't notice the `NSStringEnumerationBySentences` bit.

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this to select multiple sentences with the same keyword? I've been trying to do some sort of loop to go back and delete the range from the original but aren't having much luck.

Comment: If you know the keyword then just create an array for each keyword you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As noted in the comments there are some inherit weaknesses with my solution as it requires a perfectly formatted sentence where period + space is only used when actually ending sentences... I'll leave it in here as it could be viable for people sorting a text with another (known) separator.

Here's another way of achieving what you want:

```
NSString *wordYouAreLookingFor = @"happy";

NSArray *arrayOfSentences = [aString componentsSeparatedByString:@". "]; // get the single sentences
NSMutableArray *sentencesWithMatchingWord = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *singleSentence in arrayOfSentences) {
    NSInteger originalSize = [singleSentence length];
    NSString *possibleNewString = [singleSentence stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:wordYouAreLookingFor withString:@""];

    if (originalSize != [possibleNewString length]) {
        [sentencesWithMatchingWord addObject:singleSentence];
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if any of the text has a decimal number (i.e. "1.21 gigawatts!") or a "Mr. Smith" or if the sentence ends in a "?" or "!" etc...

Comment: Good point! You could of course change the string you compare with to ". " but it still doesn't take typos  or bad formatting into considertation.